# The error of Taylor series expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

Suppose the function $ u(x) $ has infinite amount of derivatives everywhere. I read a book about finite difference methods and they have this equation:

$$ u(x+h) = u(x) + hu'(x) + \frac{1}{2}h^2u''(x) +\frac{1}{6}h^3u'''(x) + O(h^4)  $$

Is it really true for every h, even for h that are not close to x ? how can you prove it ? If not, what is the restriction on $h$ for this to be true ?

Thanks!

Gil

Comment: This is true for every $h$. The point is that if $h$ is not small, neither will be the error, i.e. $O(h^4)$.

Comment: Say u(x) = sin(x)  how does the error term  for x=0 behave like $h^4$ ?

Comment: The equation you are talking about is just Taylor's theorem applied to Taylor polynomials of degree $3$ and functions that are $4$ times differentiable.

Comment: @Tomer The error term is equal to $$\frac1{24}h^4u''''(\xi)$$ where $$\xi\in(x,x+h).$$ This is precisely what Taylor's theorem states.

Comment: @Tomer It applies to every $h,$ and this is contained within the statement of Taylor's theorem itself. Do you know what Taylor's theorem is?

Comment: @Tomer I suggest you take a look at this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem

Comment: But $ u'''( \xi) $ can be a function of h so why the error term is $ O(h^4) $ ?

Comment: @Tomer In what sense is $u''''(\xi)$ a function of $h$? What gives you that idea?

Comment: For every h there will be a different $ \xi $ and a different value of $ u'''(\xi) $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132906/discussion-between-angel-and-tomer).